# Interceptor destroy method

Tags: java, struts2

I have created a `Authentication Interceptor` in struts2.
I have to check that when does the interceptor method get called.
so i have printed method names on console.

**Here is my code**

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("AuthenticationInterceptor destroy");

}

@Override
public void init() {
     System.out.println("AuthenticationInterceptor init");

}

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception    {
    System.out.println("AuthenticationInterceptor intercept");
    return actionInvocation.invoke();
   }
}
```

**Here is my package in struts.xml.**

```
<package name="portfolioSecure" namespace="/secure" extends="portfolio">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="ask.portfolio.utility.AuthenticationInterceptor"></interceptor>
<interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
<interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>

</interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="secureStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
    <action name="login" class="ask.portfolio.actions.Login">
        <result name="success">/loginSuccess.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

when my application starts **AuthenticationInterceptor init** get printed on console
and similarly **AuthenticationInterceptor intercept** also prints.But **AuthenticationInterceptor destroy** does not get printed even if i stop server
i want to know when **interceptors destroy method** is called and what is postprocessing in interceptor is it related with destroy method().

Comment: which version of struts2 are you using? this was a known issue and if i remember has been fixed around version 2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destroy method called only once, when the container or application is stopped or un-deployed. It called to let an interceptor clean up any resources it has allocated.